# Is there a best practice to assign a value to a scala Option when it's not initialized/None?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, variable-assignment

I have the following class where the properties are an `Option[T]`

```
class User extends IdBaseEntity[UUID] {
  var id: Option[UUID] = None
  var name: Option[String] = None
  var createdOn: Option[Date] = None
}
```

In some data access layer I need to assign these properties if they aren't set before the object is persisted to cassandra. Here are a few ways for the `createdOn` property. Are any of these the best approach or is there something better I should be doing?

**Example 1**

```
entity.createdOn = Some(entity.createdOn.map(identity).getOrElse(new Date()))
```

**Example 2**

```
entity.createdOn = entity.createdOn.orElse(Some(new Date()))
```

**Example 3**

```
entity.createdOn = entity.createdOn match {
  case None => Some(new Date())
  case _ => entity.createdOn
}
```

**Example 4**

```
entity.createdOn = entity.createdOn match {
  case None => Some(new Date())
  case Some(x) => Some(x)
}
```

**Example 5**

```
entity.createdOn match {
  case None => entity.createdOn = Some(new Date())
  case _ =>;
}
```

Comment: I would probably define a method on the `case class` that yields an instance with all incomplete fields filled with the specified defaults. (I'd do it using the tactic in (2), as Chris B suggests).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching on `Option` is not really idiomatic (IMHO). I prefer to get `orElse` or `getOrElse`. Personally I would go with example 2.

I'm not sure whether this will fit your use case, but it is more idiomatic to make `User` an immutable case class:

```
case class User(id: Option[UUID] = None, ...)
```

and `copy` it, rather than updating the fields in-place:

```
val updatedEntity = entity.copy(name = user.name.orElse(Some("Chris")))
```

Comment: Matching on `Option` is idiomatic if you need to deconstruct whatever is inside the `Some`; it used to perform better than getOrElse but I believe these days it's about the same (how much is the compiler and how much JVMs I am not sure).

Comment: Thanks for this. I've completely refactored my entire domain object structure based on everyone's feedback and, as I commented to Peter in his answer, your solution falls right inline with using a Lens from scalaz. So everything is great on that front, but now I've run across another problem which, if you're interested, can be seen in this question and has left me clueless http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348668/why-wont-astyanax-java-recognize-my-id-annotated-values-in-my-scala-case-cla

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider changing your design a bit - for two reasons:

- It looks like the User class should be read-only once initialized, so something like a case class or val instead of var would capture that requirement:

  case class User( id:UUID, name:String, createdOn:Date );
- It looks like every User is required to have an id, name, and createdOn property set, so Option[] is not a good way to model that.

I often setup a Builder class along side read-only classes to
simplify and decouple the object-construction process from
what the object represents - something like
this

```
object User {
    class Builder {
       var id:UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
       def id( v:UUID ):this.type = {id =v; this; }

       var name:String = id.toString
       def name( v:String ):this.type = { name=v; this; }

       var createdOn:Date = new Date()
       def createdOn( v:Date ):this.type = { createdOn = v; this; }

       def build():User = {
         assert( Seq(id,name,createdOn).find( _ == null ).isEmpty, "Must set all props" )
         User( user, name, createdOn )
       }
   }
}
```

Anyway - that's another way to do things ...

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i'm comparing them all now to see what works for me. did you find that builder was easier for you vs having either a case class or companion object apply where you can set whatever values you want like User(name = "Foo", id = UUID.randomUUID())  ?

Comment: Sorry I'm so late.  Yeah - both are good.  If your code is structured such that you'll set all the properties in the same block, then the case class is less code, but if you have one piece of code computing one property, then another another poperty, then it's nice to pass around a builder to collect everything ...

Answer (score 1):

Since the scenario is "get a property value and update it if some condition holds", I'd try to encapsulate access to properties. For example:

```
/**
 * Read+write access to property `P` of object `R`.
 */
case class Accessor[R,P](get: R => P, set: (R, P) => Unit) {
  /** Utility for updating values. */
  def update(record: R, modfn: P => P) =
    set(record, modfn(get(record)));
}

class User {
  var id: Option[Int] = None;
}
object User {
  // For each property of `User` we need to define an accessor,
  // but this is one time job:
  val idA: Accessor[User,Option[Int]] =
      Accessor((u: User) => u.id,
               (u: User, r: Option[Int]) => u.id = r);
}

object Test {
  import User._;

  // We can do a lot of stuff now with accessors, for example set
  // default values for `Option[...]` ones:
  def setDefault[A,B](record: A,
                      accessor: Accessor[A,Option[B]],
                      defPropVal: => B) =
    accessor.update(record, _.orElse(Some(defPropVal)));

  val user = new User();
  // Set user's id, if not defined:
  setDefault(user, idA, 42);
}
```

So instead of defining a specific method for each property for filling in default values, we define a generic accessor for each property. Then we can use them to implement all the other stuff generically.

Comment: thank you. after reading through your suggestions and Chris B's above, it seems like everything is sort of converging toward using a Lens from scalz.

Comment: @AdrianRodriguez Yes, my `Accessor` is basically a lens, the difference is that lenses are immutable (create copies) while this variant is mutable.